# increase of TableView PopOver On InCreasing tableView Cells

Tags: iphone

HI,All

I had a PopOver View ,Which consists of UItableView , and my Problem is ,i have increase the popover if cell in table view are increasing one by one,till the end of iPad VIew.......

Comment: Please edit your question and add more to it because it does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should

- post a NSNotification when adding a row, it should send as object the number of displayed rows

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"resizePopover" object:number_rows_to_show]
- in the root controller (owner of the popoverController) modify the view shown in popover:

  view..contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(your_width, your_row_height * [[notification object] intValue]);